# Google Sheet Row Binding

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

In a particular spreadsheet, I am copying data from one sheet to another using the query function. The query is:

```
=QUERY(DumpSheet! A:I, "SELECT * WHERE I = 'Potential' OR I = 'FollowUp'", 1)
```

Here's the dumpsheet, which is my source sheet. I put this query in the A1 cell in my destination sheet. So I am sending information from the A to I columns from the source sheet to the destination sheet based on the drop-down condition in the I column of the source sheet. The data is syncronizing properly. The problem is that I have created new columns from J to AJ in the destination sheet where I am inserting data of the particular people I am getting from the source sheet. But when I am changing the condition of the I column, like if I select a human as "not potential" in the I column of the source sheet, it will usually delete that person from the destination sheet. That is fine, but it's not deleting the whole row, including J to AJ, from the destination sheet. It means data in the J to AJ row remains in the same position while the row of the A to I column is going away in that case. So eventually, the data of another person is mismatched with others. How can I solve this problem?

I need to bind the whole row in the destination sheet so that if change the condition in the source sheet to take away any person from the destination sheet, It will erase the whole row in destination sheet